# button to download a pdf file using Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create button that if I click it should download the file. I work on Next js

```
    <a href={cv} download="name cv.pdf"> Download CV </a>
```

I did this code in react and run correctly but when I try it in next js I get "Failed - No file".
I'd like to figure out what's causing this issue

Comment: what is the output of this one ?

Comment: in NextJs it does the download but it says the Failed - No file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are trying to serve a static pdf file in your nextjs project.

Please make sure the file is in `public/` folder.
For eg., let's assume the file is placed in `public/cv.pdf`.

Then, the anchor tag should be

```
<a href="/cv.pdf" download="cv">Download CV</a>
```

If you're trying to serve from a cdn, please ensure the cdn link is valid.

```
<a href="https://mycdn.com/assets/cv.pdf" download="cv">Download CV</a>
```

Comment: Actually I put cv.pdf inside /puclic folder and then type inside Hero.js component this code <a href='../public/cv.pdf' download="My_File.pdf"> Download Here </a>

Comment: The href should not be '../public/cv.pdf'. It should be '/cv.pdf'

Comment: Thank you so much; it's working now. My mistake is that I was following the path of the file.

Comment: The trik for me was to understand that `/public` folder expose everything inside but not the folder itself.